# How can I code a class to have permission to add and delete contacts when the invoking user doesn't, and not use "without sharing"?

Tags: apex, managed-package

How can I code a class so that it will have permission to add and delete contact objects, even when the invoking user doesn't, and not use "without sharing" (SalesForce security review won't allow it)?

The class is an entry point in a managed package, and must pass security review, so "without sharing" is not allowed, neither is omitting the sharing clause.  The class sends emails using templates, which requires each addressee to have a Contact object.  Therefore, it must create temporary Contact objects and then delete them after the email is sent.

Comment: what if you create your contact in a trigger ? Trigger run as admin so you should be able to create and delete temporary contact

Answer (score 1):

Salesforce Security Office hours might throw more lights here but I have seen apps where if it is a valid business scenario like yours you can use without sharing and add into the false positive document and documenting the code on why you needed this to exempt CRUD/FLS should pass the review (You will need get a confirmation from security review team via office hours)

Answer (score 0):

One option is to create a separate `Custom Object` (or `Custom Setting`) to store delete requests, and then create a recurring job to check for them and perform the delete. Then you can run the recurring job as a `User` who has delete permissions, but other users can still make the request. You could even build an `Approval Process` around them if you wish.